# Is there a replacement method or function for accessing TBitmap.ScanLine in FMX?

Tags: android, ios, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

Recently, I was working on a Delphi project that used the `TBitmap.ScanLine` property to get pixel color values from a `Canvas`.  Apparently, when compiling the project for Android or iOS, it gives an error, as the `ScanLine` property doesn't exist. Any ideas?

Comment: The code you started with was written for VCL, not for FMX. It will have to be re-written a little. To access the raw pixel data of a FMX [`TBitmap`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmap), you need to use its [`Map()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmap.Map) and [`Unmap()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmap.Unmap) methods.

Comment: thanks for the answer, wouldn't have figured it out myself

Comment: You would have had you read [`TBitmap`'s documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmap): "*To directly access the bitmap data use `Map` and `Unmap` methods. The access to the bitmap data can be made for only read, only write, or read and write.*"